# Telegram bot - How to know where a inline message was sent

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am doing a bot to organize meetings with friends and I have it almost finished but I would like to keep track of all meetings shared (via switch_inline_query in the button)  into the same group. In this way, with the bot in a group it would be just a command to show all meetings shared there.

Do you know if there is any way of knowing where an inline query was sent?

Answer (score 0):

You can't know what you sent by API request, you need build database yourself.

Comment: Thanks for dropping by! I would build it but I don't see the information I want to store. For example, lets say one of the meetings is send via the inline_query, how would I track down to which chat it has been sent? I could build a database with all the chats each query was sent and then retrieve it but I don't see the chat_id anywhere when the query is sent. Is there any way I could do that?